# How do you use include tags correctly?

Tags: python, html, django, templates, inheritance

I don't understand why I am getting this error "Invalid block tag on line 29: 'includes', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?" Line 29 being the line where I have put the {% include %} tag in the INDEX.HTML file. Both of the html files below are in the same directory.

INDEX.HTML FILE

```
{% extends './base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block head_js %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!-- Page Content -->
<div>
        <!-- Header/Home -->
        <header class="w3-container w3-padding-32 w3-center w3-black" id="home">
        <h1 class="w3-jumbo"><span class="w3-hide-small">Cricket Scorer</span></h1>
        <p>A Simple Cricket Scoring Web App</p>
        </header>

        <!-- Selection Menu -->
        <div class="w3-content w3-justify w3-text-grey w3-padding-64">
                <!--button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#match-details" onclick="alert('here');">Start Scoring</button><br-->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#select-home-team">Start Scoring</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Players</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Teams</button>
        </div>
</div>

{% includes "start_scoring_modal.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

START_SCORING_MODAL.HTML

```
{% extends './index.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}


<!-- Modal Boxes -->
<div class="modal fade" id="select-home-team" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-bg">
                <div class="modal-content">
...
...
...
...
```

========================================================================
The error above was my incorrect use of syntax, using "includes" instead of "include". Now I've got a new error. The index.html gives a TemplateDoesNotExist error and flags up line 1 "{% extends "./base.html" %}".

**HOWEVER, if I remove the line with the "include" it will work fine. SO CONFUSED!!**

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% comment %} http://www.webhook.com/docs/template-inheritance-blocks/ {% endcomment %}

{% block head_js %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!-- Page Content -->
<div>
        <!-- Header/Home -->
        <header class="w3-container w3-padding-32 w3-center w3-black" id="home">
        <h1 class="w3-jumbo"><span class="w3-hide-small">Cricket Scorer</span></h1>
        <p>A Simple Cricket Scoring Web App</p>
        </header>

        <!-- Selection Menu -->
        <div class="w3-content w3-justify w3-text-grey w3-padding-64">
                <!--button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#match-details" onclick="alert('here');">Start Scoring</button><br-->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#select-home-team">Start Scoring</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Players</button><br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Teams</button>
        </div>
</div>

        {% include "./start_scoring_modal.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: “include” seems a more likely name than “includes”.

Comment: @Ryan - Thanks for that - I just made the change, but I'm getting a new error now, I've added that above.

Comment: What’s the new error?

Comment: @Ryan just added it

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `{% extends './index.html' %}` in your `start_scoring_modal.html` file.

You only need to import the added code in `start_scoring_modal.html` so you don't need to extend `index.html`.